# Template item not displaying role based user - 10.2

Tags: sitecore-client, user-management, role-management

I created the new user and assigned `designer, author, and content authoring roles` to the newly created user. Whenever I logged in as a new user some of the template items is not visible in the content tree. I have given read access for all the templates but those are not visible in the under-home item. for example, under `templates/foundation/local data source/page data` this template is not visible in under any item.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look `View` option in the menu, and ensure both `Hidden Items` and `Entire Tree` are checked.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: That works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue of conflicting access rights. To do this you need to see the details of how access rights have been granted or denied for a specific item, you can click the access right and the details appear in the pane on the right of the Access Viewer.

[image]

Here are a few links that can help you to solve the issue.

- [Conflicting access rights](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/the-inheritance-access-right.html#UUID-6ad34adf-a978-94f7-ec49-9111134f1e7e_N1525261971752)
- [Examples of how to control access with the Inheritance access right](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/the-inheritance-access-right.html#examples-of-how-to-control-access-with-the-inheritance-access-right)

Hope this helps.